# Obtain array objects with specific value

Tags: objective-c, object, numbers, nsarray

What I want to do is to return the NSArray objects of a specific value (numbers).
How can I do it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `return @[ 1, 2, 42, 1337 ];`

Comment: And where's the question about Xcode?

Comment: @H2CO3, those need to be NSNumber literals.

Comment: @MattWilding Correct, thanks, of course. Maybe I should go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` on your `NSArray` instance.

```
NSArray *array = @[1, 2, 3];

typedef BOOL (^Predicate)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop);
Predicate predicate = ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        *stop = YES;
        return YES;
    } else return NO;
};

NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:predicate];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW24

Comment: Thank you, but what I need (I did not explain it properly)is, for example,return any type of number

Comment: @Alrro I updated the answer. You can probably use `isKindOfClass:` or you might have to write a more exhaustive test, but the mechanism is the same.